# iOS 4 background HTTP Live Stream

Tags: iphone, audio, ios4, http-live-streaming

I'd like to play an audio HTTP Live Stream in background. But how do I do that?

I tried to add the key (an Array) "UIBackgroundModes" with value "audio" to the info.plist. Now I try to play audio with the MPMoviePlayerController. But as soon as the app goes into background, the audio Playback stops! I don't know of any other API to play a HTTP Live Stream on the iPhone. So is there an other or am I doing something wrong?
I searched all over the apple documentation but couldn't find anything useful. There isn't much about background audio in the docs :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a soluton:
setting `useApplicationAudioSession` to `NO` on the MPMoviePlayerController does the job. But it works only on audio only streams. Video streams still stop.

```
player.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1668.html for a description of what changed in iOS4 and how to implement the functionality you want.

This works for me in one of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your audio session category to kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback might work.