# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't play the next URL when in background

Tags: ios

I have an app which downloads a list of URLs to mp3 files then plays them using MPMoviePlayerController.

I have the following in the app delegate:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

When I put the application in the background it continues to play the current track. Then I get notified when MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification happens and then, in the case of MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded (thus success), I am trying to play the next URL. However it doesn't work. Nothing happens.

However, if at this point in time I bring the app back to foreground, then the playback resumes correctly. It's like MPMoviePlayerController cannot start the playback of a new URL while in background, but it correctly resumes it when brought back into foreground.

Here's the code that does the playback (in the callback):

```
self.moviePlayer.contentURL = aUrl;
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

Any ideas why this happens?

BTW, it happens on iOS 4.3.3 (and some of my testers told me it happens on 4.2.8 as well), however on iOS 5 it appears to work (I did some testing myself and it worked, however I still have to check with the testers).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the fix from [iOS 4 background HTTP Live Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280097/ios-4-background-http-live-stream) applied to me as well.

Once I set the property `useApplicationAudioSession` of `MPMoviePlayerController` to `NO`, it started working.